# Source list in mac m1?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, apt

I had a copy of `source-list` from my ubuntu machine and I double clicked it mistakenly ran it successfully in my m1 macbook machine.

It may or may not affect my machine but I want to undo this action. Obviously, undoing is not possible. But where can I find source-list in mac machine so I can remove them manually?

The `source-list` file contains the contents like this:

```
deb http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
```

Comment: How did you determine it ran "successfully"?

Comment: When I clicked the file it ran in terminal with process completed message.